# Do username have to be unique in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: members, database, fields

I am in the process of importing data from another application to ExpressionEngine. I know that EE expects screen_names to be unique as of Sept 2012.

The question is whether I have to make the username unique too or if I can use a combination of first name and last name (e.g. "johndoe") risking that there might be more then one "john doe" in the imported data.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If the username isn't important, I've used this for unique usernames:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="whateve_{current_time format="%m%d%Y_%G%i%s"}">
```

This would typically be used in a member registration form or any other add-on that handles the registration process. Just hide the input so the user never sees the field.

Answer (score 6):

Yup; a username is required and must be unique.

Comment: A good option is to have the users email address or similar as username when you are doing an import. Or to echo out a random string generated by PHP or similar.

Comment: Off topic comment, why do screen names need to unique? I thought only username and email had to unique.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If you have access to email addresses, they might be unique and could be used as usernames. Some member management add-ons offer this option as well.

Answer (score 2):

after some research I can confirm that the following 3 fields need to be unique

- username
- screen_name
- email

thanks for the tip with the current time - this and a random string is a good way to go about it.